# How to remove the question mark symbol in reference group row of gtsummary regression table?

Tags: gtsummary

I used tbl_regression to visualize my main effects (see image and code below), and I'm wondering how to get rid of the question mark symbol in the confidence interval column for my reference group ("Neutral"). add_estimate_to_reference_rows only adds the null value for the OR.  A horizontal line or a null 95% CI would look better than the question mark symbol in the CI column.

m.crude.cat %>% tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE, add_estimate_to_reference_rows = TRUE)

[tbl_regression output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiF13.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question make is an em-dash, and it looks like there is some kind of encoding issue on your machine. You can change the em-dash to anything else, however. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

tbl <-
  glm(response ~ grade, trial, family = binomial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE, 
                 add_estimate_to_reference_rows = TRUE) %>%
  modify_table_styling(
    columns = c(estimate, ci),
    rows = reference_row %in% TRUE,
    missing_symbol = "Ref."
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>